# Neural Network Stuck at Low Accuracy

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am new to deep learning so forgive me if this is an obvious mistake, I have tried to find similar questions online yet none seem relevant to my problem.

I am using pytorch for image classification and my accuracy is stuck at ~40% even though my framework seems fine. Am I missing something major? My data has 5 columns: Age, Gender, Ethnicity, Image name , and "pixel" values (which are already scaled). I want to target the "ethnicity" output, which has 5 classes.

A problem I spotted is that when I pass the training data into my model, the output tensor is 5 values (for 5 different classes), and the value at index 0 is always the lowest negative value (the argmax), making much of my models predictions the ethnicity at index 0.

I have also tried training on 100 epochs but the accuracy and loss remains relatively the same. Here is my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("age_gender.csv")
data['pixels']=data['pixels'].apply(lambda x:  np.array(x.split(), dtype="float32"))
data['pixels'] = data['pixels'].apply(lambda x: x/255)

X = np.array(data['pixels'].tolist())
X = X.reshape(X.shape[0],48,48,1)

X = torch.tensor(X)
y = torch.tensor(data['ethnicity'])

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=37, shuffle = True)
```

Model

```
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module): 
  def __init__(self):
    super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
    self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
    self.linear_relu_stack = nn.Sequential(
      nn.Linear(48*48,64),
      nn.ReLU(),
      nn.Linear(64, 64),
      nn.ReLU(),
      nn.Linear(64, 5))

 def forward(self, x): 
   x = self.flatten(x)
   logits = self.linear_relu_stack(x)
   return F.log_softmax(logits, dim=1)

model = NeuralNetwork()
```

BACKPROP, LOSS, OPTIMIZER

```
import torch.optim as optim
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

for epoch in range(3): 
  optimizer.zero_grad() 
  output = model(X_train.view(-1,48*48))  
  loss = loss_fn(output, y_train) 
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step() 
  print(loss)  

  >>>output
   >tensor(1.4611, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward0>)
   >tensor(1.4678, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward0>)
   >tensor(1.4475, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward0>)


correct = 0
total = 0

with torch.no_grad(): # we dont want to calculate gradients
  output = model(X_test.view(-1, 2304))
  for index, i in enumerate(output):
    if torch.argmax(i) == y_test[index]:
      correct += 1
    total += 1

 print("acc:", round(correct/total, 3))

>>>acc: 42.5
```

Comment: There can be multiple 'problems' that cause a relatively low accuracy which can be difficult to troubleshoot without having the data. How long are you training the network for? The example you have provided only shows you running three epochs, which is likely too few for the network to recognize all available patterns in the data.

Comment: @Oxbowerce, I have also tested 100 epochs, but the loss and accuracy remain relatively the same

Comment: Then it might be the case that the current model architecture is too simple to achieve a better performance. Have you tried increasing the number of neurons in the fully connected layers, or even adding some convolutional layers?

Comment: Just a suggestion: try to predict gender first, it should be an easier task. This would allow you to check that the model works before moving to ethnicity. Btw I wouldn't be surprised that ethnicity can't be predicted very well, it's scientifically proven that there is not way to completely separate races.